# Add-On Dev: Open external file with default program

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, development

I was planning to create some simple help-like text or HTML documents in a local folder of my add-on, and provide "help" buttons on the panels to allow the user to access them from each section that relates to that file.

Is there a way to open these files using the user's default program from within Blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a wiki URL (`"wiki_url"`) to the `bl_info` of your add-on. This will result in a link to the documentation in the add-on preferences. Alternatively you can use [`bpy.ops.wm.url_open(url="")`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.url_open) in your code to open the browser.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks rjg. I also found that you can use `subprocess` to open any file type with its default program: `import subprocess (next-line) subprocess.run( "C:\\Temp\\Test.txt", shell=True)`